# Checking if a Process Object has been assigned a value and is running in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am creating a Process object in c# and need to check and see if it has been assigned a value before using it. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to do so? Please and Thanks. Here is what I have tried that hasn't worked:

```
 (proc != null && !proc.HasExited)
```

When I try to hit this code I get:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException] {"No process is associated with this object."}
```

Comment: "Hasn't worked" is not an error description we can help you with. What happened? Why aren't you happy with the result?

Comment: Can you not somehow arrange things so that you never have to deal with a `Process` object that's not already associated with a running process - i.e. I'd imagine from your description that `proc` is a variable shared between multiple threads. Can you not arrange for whichever thread *initializes* `proc` actually use a *local* variable until it's actually started the process, and only then assign a non-null value to `proc`? In that way, the code you already have would be sufficient.

Comment: That worked out perfectly. Thank you so much. I just had been beating my head against it and the obvious solution was too simple to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the answer that got me to a point that I could answer my underlying questions

> Can you not somehow arrange things so that you never have to deal with a Process object that's not already associated with a running process - i.e. I'd imagine from your description that proc is a variable shared between multiple threads. Can you not arrange for whichever thread initializes proc actually use a local variable until it's actually started the process, and only then assign a non-null value to proc? In that way, the code you already have would be sufficient. –  @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oct 8 '14 at 14:51

Comment: If you provide the answer from an other user, it is customary to make it a community wiki.

Comment: If you click [edit] there is a small community wiki checkbox under the form on the right side. You can of course flesh out your answer, and then nobody will have a problem with it.